# free groups of rotations

Tags: rotations, free-groups, spheres

The question of which pairs of rotations of the sphere are independent goes back to Hausdorff, who produced such a pair a century ago. "Independent" means "are free generators of a free group". The following assertion might not be true, but its statement is certainly elegant! Maybe there is a simple counterexample?

Question:  If A and B are noncommuting rotations of a sphere of infinite order, then A and B are independent.

One can also consider finite order (as did Hausdorff who used order 2 and 3):

If A and B are noncommuting rotations of a sphere, then A and B A Inverse(B) are independent.

Can such strong and general assertions possibly be true?

Stan Wagon

Comment: Love your Banach-Tarski book. And your square-wheeled bicycle.

Comment: 30 years on, I am working (with G. Tomkowicz) on revising the BTP book. Big job. Almost finished. That is where this question arose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: If A and B are noncommuting rotations of a sphere of infinite order, then A and B are independent.

No, this is too strong. Let $w \in F_2$ be a word which does not vanish in the abelianization. Then [it's known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45483/word-maps-on-compact-lie-groups) that the induced map

$$\text{SO}(3) \times \text{SO}(3) \ni (A, B) \mapsto w(A, B) \in \text{SO}(3)$$

is surjective. So we can find $A, B$ such that, for example, $A [A, B] = -1$. With a little more care (to check that the derivative of the word map is surjective, so that the word map is a submersion) we should be able to show that there are enough of these that we can arrange for $A$ and $B$ to both have infinite order. This gives a counterexample to both of your questions.

What is true is that if $A$ and $B$ are chosen randomly then with probability $1$ they generate a free group. In fact the subspace of pairs $(A, B)$ which don't generate a free group is a countable union of Zariski-closed subspaces (and in particular has measure zero, but this is a stronger statement).

Comment: Many thanks. It might be nice to have a specific examples of the 3x3 matrices that do not commute but satisfy a word such as you suggested, but I don't really need that. It is enough to know that the theorem is false, and so this adds to the value of the many theorems that say that certain pairs of rotations are independent.

Comment: So that assertion is too strong. What about this:   If A and B are noncommuting rotations of infinite order, then G, the group they generate, has a free subgroup of rank 2.

Comment: @stan: by the Tits alternative (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tits_alternative), it suffices to check that $G$ is not virtually solvable. I suspect that solvable subgroups of $\text{SO}(3)$ are pretty highly constrained (maybe they're virtually abelian?), but I don't know off the top of my head what those constraints are. That would be worth asking as a separate question, I think.